# CryptoJS encryption/decryption example with binary files on clients sites

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I want use CryptoJS for encrypt/decrypt only on client site.
But I can't find why is my code working incorrect. Encryption looks ok but I am not able to decrypt after I encrypt some binary file. Maybe it is because I am using wrong encryption parameters in my code for encrypt binary file. 
I am attaching my code which I am using to encrypt binary file (mp3, avi or other) but no luck with it. It is possible to tell me where I am making mistake?
I was also looking for some examples where I will be able to see possible usage of CryptoJS for binary file but I spend two days on internet and didn't find relevant answer. There are many examples for encryption on client site and decryption on server site but didn't find any example of client site encryption client site decryption (pure javascript implementation)...
Therefore I am asking here which is my final try to find solution to my problem. Any help will be grateful!!!
THX

I am using CryptoJS v3.1.2

```
$("#ffle").change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var key =  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("Halo");
    var iv =  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("123");

    reader.onload = function (e) {

        var encdata = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(e.target.result), key,
        {
            keySize: 256,
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,    //padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        var finData = encodeURIComponent(encdata);
        var form_data = new FormData();                 
        form_data.append('file_enc', finData);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    

        xhr.open('POST', 'https://crypt.xxxxxxx.net/fileenc4/save.php', true); 
        xhr.send(form_data);
        xhr.onload = function () {

        };

    }

    reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);     
});
```

Comment: Is the `save.php` call actually saving the file to the users computer?

Comment: Please don't use CryptoJS use SJCL ( https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/ ) if you care about security.

Comment: Derek no this call where is save.php is for saving file on server. I am not looking to save this file on users computer. I want run encryption on users computer and after encryption is done I want save this encrypted file to the server. And then I want other users to download this encrypted file from server and decrypt this file again on his computer. Did I explain it good? Please let me know. thx

Comment: Yoni Jah. THX for this Tip but can I use this Stanford Javascript Crypto Library also for pure client to client AES binary files encryption/decryption??

Comment: @Danco yes you can, but you'll need to dig a bit in the docs to understand how to do it properly. It shouldn't be very hard but if you get stuck the code review stackexchange might be a better place to get help. Also probably be easier to use jQuery or a plain ajax library to send the data